# Installing CKAN with Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckan

I have created a website using [Drupal](http://www.carbontrackandtrace.com).

On the site, there is a tab called "Data".

What I want to do, is to install CKAN so that it can be used within the "Data"-section of carbontrackandtrace. That way I can pull data from different databases and display it on the "Data" page of [carbontrackandtrace.com](http://carbontrackandtrace.com).

I am completely new to both Drupal and CKAN, and I can't seem to even understand where to start. I have tried installing CKAN by logging in on the server using SSH terminal, but I don't think I have the permission to install CKAN even after I log in with username and password.

How do I go about installing CKAN so that I can host a CKAN site "within" the "Data" section of the website?

Any help is much appreciated as I'm completely stuck right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need admin rights on the server to install new software, such as CKAN, so ask your sysadmin for this.

CKAN install instructions are here: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html and if you're not on ubuntu then you're going off the beaten track and it's not for beginners.

You will need to set-up your apache/nginx config to send requests to CKAN paths to CKAN (rather than Drupal) e.g. /dataset, /organization etc.

To connect Drupal to CKAN then you'll need to just add a link in the menu bar to the CKAN search page: /dataset

In CKAN I imagine you'd want to have links back to Drupal, so you'd customize your CKAN templates, which involved creating an extension. See: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's really helpfull! I'll start by contacting the sysadmin and then go from there.

Comment: Good. In which case please mark this as the 'answer'.